# Showing that the free group of a disjoint union is isomorphic to the free product of the corresponding free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, free-groups, free-product

[P. Aluffi's *"Algebra: Chapter $\it 0$"*](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-104), exercise II.$5.8$.

> Still more generally, prove that $F(A\amalg B)=F(A)*F(B)$ and that $F^{ab}(A\amalg B)=F^{ab}(A)\oplus F^{ab}(B)$ for all sets $A,B$. $($That is, the constructions $F,F^{ab}$ 'preserve coproducts'.$)$

Here $F(A)$ is the free groups on the set $A$, $A\amalg B$ is the disjoint union of $A$ and $B$, and $G*H$ is the free product of $G$ and $H$ (i.e. the coproduct in $\sf Grp$). All of those are characterized by their usual universal properties which will be used extensively for the proof.$^*$

*Proof.* We will show that $F(A\amalg B)$ satisfies the universal property of $F(A)*F(B)$. For startes, we will construct the (canonical) inclusion homomorphisms. Thus, consider the following diagrams

[image]

Here $\iota_A,\iota_B,\iota$ are the inclusion of $A,B,A\amalg B$ into their respective free groups. The (unique) group homomorphisms $I_A,I_B$ are induced by considering the compositions $\iota\circ i_B$ and $\iota\circ i_B$ and the universal properties of $F(A)$ and $F(B)$. Hence they are such that
$$I_A\circ\iota_A=\iota\circ i_A,~~~I_B\circ\iota_B=\iota\circ i_B$$
Now, suppose we are given group homomorphisms $g_A\colon F(A)\to G,\,g_B\colon F(B)\to G$ to some arbitrary group $G$. We can consider them in particular as set-functions and precomposing with $\iota_A$ and $\iota_B$, respectively, gives us the following

[image]

The unique map $g$ is given by the universal property of $A\amalg B$ and such that
$$g\circ i_A=g_A\circ\iota_A,~~~g\circ i_B=g_B\circ\iota_B$$
Finally, $\overline{g}$ induces a unique map $\overline{f}$ such that

[image]

by the universal property of $F(A\amalg B)$ and so $\overline{g}\circ\iota=g$. Composing gives us uniquely determined group homomorphisms $\overline{g}\circ I_A\colon F(A)\to G$ and $\overline{g}\circ I_B\colon F(B)\to G$ factoring through $F(A\amalg B)$. It remains to show the following

$$\overline{g}\circ I_A=g_A,~~~\overline{g}\circ I_B=g_B$$

But using the given commutativity relations we see that

$$(\overline{g}\circ I_A)\circ\iota_A=\overline{g}\circ(I_A\circ\iota_A)=\overline{g}\circ(\iota\circ i_A)=(\overline{g}\circ\iota)\circ i_A=g\circ i_A=g_A\circ\iota_A$$

and hence both triangles in the following diagram commute

[image]

The right triangle corresponds to the fact the by $g_A\circ\iota_A$ universally induced map is $g_A$ itself. But from the left triangles we see that $\overline{f}\circ I_A$ makes the corresponding diagram commute as well and hence $\overline{f}\circ I_A=g_A$ by the uniquesness of the induced map. The same argument, with all $A$s replaced by $B$s, yields $\overline{f}\circ I_B=g_B$. Thus, we conclude that $F(A\amalg B)$ satisfies the universal property of $F(A)*F(B)$ as every pair of group homomorphisms $g_A\colon F(A)\to G,\,g_B\colon F(B)\to G$ factors uniquely through $F(A\amalg B)$ using $I_A,I_B$ and $\overline{g}$. Hence, $F(A\amalg B)\cong F(A)*F(B)$.

The argument is precisely the same for $F^{ab}$ where we note that $G*H=G\oplus H=G\times H$ for abelian groups.   $\square$

> Is the given proof correct; if so, can it be (substantially) improved? If not, where did I went wrong? I am not sure how to show actual equality instead 'mere' isomorphy (which is enough for me, to be honest) and the last part, i.e. showing that $\overline{g}\circ I_A=g_A$, is a little bit sketchy to me, even though I am quite sure the argument works.

Thanks in advance!

---

$^*$ I know that this preservation essentially boils down to 'left adjoints presever colimits' as the (binary) coproduct is a simple colimit and the free functor $F\colon\sf{Set}\to\sf{Grp}$ is left adjoint to the forgetful functor $\sf{Grp}\to\sf{Set}$. However, I would like to *not* dabble to deep into category theoretic terrain if it does not make the proof easier/more understandable. So the given proof is more or less from scratch.

Comment: Well, I just now found [this Math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203904/proving-the-free-group-for-a-amalg-b-is-equal-to-the-coproduct-of-free-groups) talking about that $=$ should be replaced by $\cong$. So this part is clear now.

Comment: I don't know whether it's just my phone but your diagrams are too small.

Comment: @Shaun I hope it's better now?

Comment: Much better, yes; thank you :)

Comment: @Shaun They came out smaller than I expected; it's a shame that Math.SE does not support 
`tikzcd` which would make this whole thing much easier to format :D

Comment: I would think it easier to show that $F(A)*F(B)$ satisfies the universal property of $F(A\amalg B)$: given a map $A\amalg B\to G$, the restriction to $A$ gives a map $F(A)\to G$, and the restriction to $B$ gives a map $F(B)\to G$, and the two give a map $F(A)*F(B)\to G$; and then proving uniqueness...

Comment: I will note that if your free groups and free products are defined in terms of reduced words, then you *can* show “actual equality.” Essentially, showing the underlying sets are the same, and the multiplication rules in both agree on any given pair of elements.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for your input! I'll go over the first suggestion as soon as I can. What exactly do you mean by 'the restriction to $A$/$B$' though? Regarding your second comment: while the free group was constructed in a such a way, Aluffi refrains from talking about the free product (at least up to this chapter) as anything more than the coproduct in $\sf Grp$ characterised by a universal property.

Comment: You have a map $f\colon A\amalg B\to X$; the “restriction to $A$” is just the composite of the canonical embedding $i_A\colon A\to A\amalg B$ with $f$, and the restriction to $B$ is similar. We usually think of $A$ and $B$ as subsets of their disjoint union, in which case “restriction” has its usual meaning. If you don’t have an explicit description of the coproduct, then of course you cannot prove that the coproduct is literally equal to the free group: you don’t even know what the coproduct looks like, after all!

Comment: On quick look, it does appear the argument you give is correct. I still think showing the *other* property is easier, because you don’t need to find embeddings of groups, just of sets. And you get a map $A\amalg B\to F(A)*F(B)$ from the universal property of the disjoint union (I glossed over this before).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let me argue for proving the other universal property; that is, showing that $F(A)*F(B)$ has the universal property of $F(A\amalg B)$.

Let $u_A\colon A\to F(A)$ and $u_B\colon B\to F(B)$ be the canonical maps from the set to the corresponding free group. Let $\iota_A\colon F(A)\to F(A)*F(B)$ and $\iota_B\colon F(B)\to F(A)*F(B)$ be the canonical inclusions into the free product. And let $j_A\colon A\to A\amalg B$ and $j_B\colon B\to A\amalg B$ be the set-theoretic inclusions into the disjoint union/set-theoretic coproduct.

We want to show that there is a map $u_{A\amalg B}\colon A\amalg B\to F(A)*F(B)$ such that for every group $G$ and every set-theoretic map $f\colon A\amalg B\to G$, there exists a unique group homomorphism $\mathscr{F}\colon F(A)*F(B)\to G$ such that $\mathscr{F}\circ u_{A\amalg B}=f$.

So, first, the maps $\iota_A\circ u_A\colon A\to F(A)*F(B)$ and $\iota_B\circ u_B\colon B\to F(A)*F(B)$ yield a unique map $u_{A\amalg B}\to F(A)*F(B)$ such that $u_{A\amalg B}\circ j_A=\iota_A\circ u_A$ and $u_{A\amalg B}\circ j_B=\iota_B\circ u_B$.

Now let $f\colon A\amalg B\to G$. The map $f\circ j_A\colon A\to G$ induces a morphism $F_A\colon F(A)\to G$ with $F_A\circ u_A=f\circ j_A$; similarly, we have a morphism $F_B\colon F(B)\to G$ with $F_B\circ u_B=f\circ j_B$. And the maps $F_A$ and $F_B$ induce a morphism $\mathscr{F}\colon F(A)*F(B)\to G$ with $\mathscr{F}\circ \iota_A=F_A$ and $\mathscr{F}\circ \iota_B=F_B$. We want to show that this $\mathscr{F}$ satisfies $\mathscr{F}\circ u_{A\amalg B}=f$, and that it is the unique map with this property.

The universal property of $A\amalg B$ tells us that $f$ is the unique map $g\colon A\amalg B\to G$ such that $g\circ j_A=f\circ j_A$ and $g\circ j_B=f\circ j_B$. So if we can prove that $\mathscr{F}\circ u_{A\amalg B}$ also has this property, then we will have the equality with $f$.

Now,
$$\begin{align*}
(\mathscr{F}\circ u_{A\amalg B})\circ j_A&=\mathscr{F}\circ (u_{A\amalg B}\circ j_A)\\
&= \mathscr{F}\circ (i_A\circ u_A)\\
&=(\mathscr{F}\circ i_A)\circ u_A\\
&= F_A\circ u_A\\
&= f\circ j_A;\\
(\mathscr{F}\circ u_{A\amalg B})\circ j_B &= \mathscr{F}\circ (u_{A\amalg B}\circ j_B)\\
&= \mathscr{F}\circ (i_B\circ u_B)\\
&= (\mathscr{F}\circ i_B)\circ u_B\\
&= F_B\circ u_B\\
&= f\circ j_B.
\end{align*}$$
Therefore, $\mathscr{F}\circ u_{A\amalg B}=f$, as desired.

As for uniqueness, let $\mathscr{G}\colon F(A)*F(B)\to G$ be such that $\mathscr{G}\circ u_{A\amalg B} = f$. We want to show that $\mathscr{G}=\mathscr{F}$. Since $\mathscr{F}$ is the unique map such that $\mathscr{F}\circ i_A=F_A$ and $\mathscr{F}\circ i_B=F_B$, it is enough to show that $\mathscr{G}$ has this property as well.

To show that $\mathscr{G}\circ i_A=F_A$, it is enough to show that it has the universal property of $F_A$, namely, that $(\mathscr{G}\circ i_A)\circ u_A=f\circ j_A$. And, indeed,
$$\begin{align*}
(\mathscr{G}\circ i_A)\circ u_A &= \mathscr{G}\circ (i_A\circ u_A)\\
&= \mathscr{G}\circ(u_{A\amalg B}\circ j_A)\\
&= (\mathscr{G}\circ u_{A\amalg B})\circ j_A\\
&= f\circ j_A,
\end{align*}$$
as desired. Thus, $\mathscr{G}\circ i_A=F_A$, as needed. Symmetrically, $\mathscr{G}\circ i_B=F_B$. This proves that $\mathscr{G}=\mathscr{F}$, giving uniqueness, and we are done.

Comment: Thank you kindly! I've gone through it myself before and realised that this is a nice alternative. As you've already commented on my own proof I'll accept your answer. Thanks again.